# Terraform : How to obtain value from list containing map

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-acm

I have a terraform output for acm_certificate [domain_validation_options](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#domain_validation_options)

the output is something of this type. I want to extract resource_record_value and resource_record_name

```
     ~ base_module_outputs = {
          + acm_certificate_name = [
              + {
                  + domain_name           = "xxxx"
                  + resource_record_name  = "xxxxx"
                  + resource_record_type  = "CNAME"
                  + resource_record_value = "xxxx"
                },
            ]
            # (2 unchanged elements hidden)
        }
```

root module outputs.tf

```
output "base_module_outputs" {
  value = module.base
}
```

base module outputs.tf

```
output "acm_certificate_name" {
  value = aws_acm_certificate.xx.domain_validation_options
}
```

Comment: You want to extract that from the `base_module_outputs` output or `acm_certificate_name` output?

Comment: I want to extract from `acm_certificate_name`. So basically extraction should happened inside base module. 

root module should output what base module provides it.

Comment: Would `module.base.acm_certificate_name["resource_record_value"]` and `module.base.acm_certificate_name["resource_record_name"]` work?

Comment: I am actual outputting 2 more value with resource_record_value and resource_record_name so in total 4 value. This will restrict me to only two values. 
that is why I wanted to do the extraction inside base module and not root module

Comment: I can see you are, but where do you need those outputs to be? Where do you want to use them?

Comment: will be displayed on console so that users can copy this value and update it manually. this is a required step, cannot be changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254459/discussion-between-jatin-mehrotra-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output value needs to be present in the base module outputs, here's how to get it:

```
output "acm_certificate_name" {
  value = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.xx.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_value
}
```

The explicit conversion to a list (using [`tolist` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/tolist)) is required here as the [`domain_validation_options` attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#domain_validation_options) is a set:

> `domain_validation_options` - Set of domain validation objects which can be used to complete certificate validation. [...]

Hence `domain_validation_options` has no indexes. The same type of logic can be applied to the second required output which references the `resource_record_name`.

---

EDIT: As suggest in the comments (h/t: @Matt Schuchard), the safer way to fetch the values is by using the [`one` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one). The above code would then change to:

```
output "acm_certificate_name" {
  value = one(aws_acm_certificate.xx.domain_validation_options).resource_record_value
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this should be `one(aws_acm_certificate.xx.domain_validation_options).resource_record_value` because a set is unordered, and therefore the `0` element after list conversion could change between applications for no apparent reason. Using the `one` function guarantees an error if the number of elements is ever not one, and this seems safer to me as it guarantees the output value only changes if `aws_acm_certificate.xx.domain_validation_options` changes.

Comment: Sure, I'll add your suggestion to the answer, thanks, I'm learning as well from this. :)